wdiwifi.sys seemingly causing crashes and BSODs?
I've had my laptop for a while now (Lenovo Yoga slim 7). I've encountered this problem that when I close the lid, the pc will completely shut everything off and reboot on the next opening of the lid. Sometimes, it doesn't do this, but generates a BSOD.
For years I've been trying to just ignore it and live with it. Recently I decided to really look into it.
I updated all the drivers (and hidden drivers) as well as the BIOS. Some people online recommended disabling 'Performance Boost Mode', which I did using QuickCPU.
I scanned for malware and viruses many a time, but to no avail. Even factory resetting didn't do the trick.
I went into event viewer which showed something about an AMD certificate. I looked into the DMP file only to see that every single time, wdiwifi.sys is acting up (I checked this for the last 12 DMP files).
Is this responsible for the BSODs? Is it the wi-fi direct adapter? If so, what do I do to fix this?
For the latest DMP file.
